# Incremental Training of object detection models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, object-detection

I currently have an object detection model which is deployed and working. But my client expects to have more variants of the input images, which may be ideally added to the training base and new training must be carried out.

Basically all I have is a trained model and some new data.

**How should I proceed with further training with the new data?**

1. Can I start from the previous checkpoint and run the training for a certain number of epochs only with new data?
2. Load the weights from the previous model and start the training all over again only with new data?
3. Add the new data to the old existing data, and start the fresh training all over again?

Note - I run all of these in google cloud ML Engine. So both data volume and computation time is money and I need to strike the right balance between both.